# How to use Arabic language characters in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, encoding, character-encoding, arabic

I'm trying to log this Arabic word by this code:

```
def test = "اضافة ";

context.log(java.net.URLEncoder.encode(test,"UTF-8"));
context.log(test);
```

but the result in log messages is:

```
%3F%3F%3F%3F%3F+
?????
```

How to fix that?

Comment: `%3F` is the question mark. That means that `def test = ...` already doesn't work. It seems like your source file is not interpreted in the correct encoding. Either fix how you build/run it (by specifying the correct encoding of the source file(s)) or avoid the issue by using `\u` escapes to represent non-ASCII characters in your source files.

Comment: What encoding are you using?  E.g. `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

Comment: What logging api are you using?